# Area of a triangle using 1/2 bh on a lattice graph

Tags: geometry, area

[image: triangle of area 0.5 on a lattice grid]

I'm trying to find the area of this triangle using the $\frac{1}{2} \times b \times h$ formula, but for some reason, it isn't quite working out. My workings:

### My working:

[image: working]

$$\alpha = \sqrt{1^{2}+1^{2}} = \sqrt{2}$$
$$\beta = \sqrt{2^{2} + 2^{2}} = 2\sqrt{2}$$

$$\frac{1}{2} \times \sqrt{2} \times 2\sqrt{2} = 2?$$

I know the area is supposed to be 0.5 units^2, so what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: $\beta$ is clearly not the height if you take $\alpha$ to be your base.

Comment: @Shane You can use [Pick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The altitude is measured *perpendicular* to the (extended) base line.
In your case, $h=\dfrac{\sqrt2}{2}$

Comment: If we call alpha the base then, by running the third point parallel to the base down to the bottom row, the height is  $\frac{ \sqrt{2}} 2$

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7An3.png

Like this?

Answer (score 0):

In your diagram, why did you take $\beta$ to be the diagonal of a $(2,2)$ square instead of the diagonal of a $(1,1)$ square? What it should be is the distance from the upper right end of $\alpha$ to the other side of the triangle.  You can evaluate that by choosing one of the dots to be the origin of a coordinate system and writing the equations for $\beta$ and the base of the triangle, then finding the intersection.  You should then find the distance from the upper right of $\alpha$ to that point to get the height of the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood. $\alpha$ an $\beta$ must be at $90$ degree. BUt the angle between your $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is not $90$. Instead you could have taken this figure

[image]

Here $\alpha$ and $\beta$ form 90 degree angle. Just now use the formula $$ \frac{1}{2} \cdot \beta \cdot (\alpha + \text{dotted line length}) $$

Comment: Dotted line length? That's not needed, is it?

Comment: See if you inclue in $\alpha$ length the dotted part then dotted part isn't needed however if you take alpha only as the connected line not the dotted line then it is not needed